# Retrieve Array of array with getRessources Android Studio

Tags: android, arrays, xml, android-studio

I've something like this in my java code to try to receive the array of array.
Actually I try to do a Quizz in French, the fact is, **IT WORKS** but I have to translate it, so on purpose I need to use XML files for questions anwsers ect.

```
    public String mChoices[][] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.choices_array);
```

On the other hand in my XML string I have done an array of array like this :

```
<string-array name="question_array">
    <item>A quelle fréquence manger vous de la viande ?</item>
    <item>Combien de temps dur en moyenne votre douche ?</item>
    <item>A quelle fréquence recyclez vous ?</item>
    <item>Votre production de déchét par rapport a votre voisin ?</item>
    <item>Combien de temps par jour mettez vous le chauffage chez vous ?</item>
    <item>Faites vous toujours attention a éteindre les lumières ?</item>
</string-array>

<array name="choices_array">
    <item>
        <array name="choice01">
            <item>Zéro fois par semaines</item>
            <item>Une fois par semaines</item>
            <item>Entre deux et trois fois par semaines</item>
            <item>Quatre fois et plus par semaines</item>
        </array>
    </item>
    <item>
        <array name="choice02">
            <item>Moins de 6 minutes</item>
            <item>Entre 6 et 10 minutes</item>
            <item>Entre 10 et 15 minutes</item>
            <item>Plus de 15 minutes</item>
        </array>
    </item>
    <item>
        <array name="choice03">
            <item>Jamais</item>
            <item>Presque jamais</item>
            <item>Parfois</item>
            <item>Toujours</item>
        </array>
    </item>
    <item>
        <array name="choice04">
            <item>Moins que mon voisin</item>
            <item>Equivalent a mon voisin</item>
            <item>Légèrement plus que mon voisin</item>
            <item>Considérablement plus que mon voisin</item>
        </array>
    </item>
    <item>
        <array name="choice05">
            <item>Il n'est jamais allumé</item>
            <item>Entre une et deux heures</item>
            <item>Entre trois et quatre heures</item>
            <item>Quatre heures et plus</item>
        </array>
    </item>
    <item>
        <array name="choice06">
            <item>Jamais</item>
            <item>Presque jamais</item>
            <item>Parfois</item>
            <item>Toujours</item>
        </array>
    </item>
</array>
```

The fact is i want something that look like this :

```
private String mChoices[][] = {
            {"Zéro fois par semaines", "Une fois par semaines", "Entre deux et trois fois par semaines", "Quatre fois et plus par semaines"},
            {"Moins de 6 minutes", "Entre 6 et 10 minutes", "Entre 10 et 15 minutes", "Plus de 15 minutes"},
            {"Jamais", "Presque jamais", "Parfois", "Toujours"},
            {"Moins que mon voisin", "Equivalent a mon voisin", "Légèrement plus que mon voisin", "Considérablement plus que mon voisin"},
            {"Il n'est jamaais allumé", "Entre une et deux heures", "Entre trois et quatre heures", "Quatre heures et plus"},
            {"Jamais", "Presque jamais", "Parfois", "Toujours"}
    };
```

If anybody have an answer, would be greatfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way :

`String choice1[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.choice01);
String choice2[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.choice02);
String choice3[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.choice03);`

and then I recreated the Array of Array by using

```
private String mChoices[][] = {
   choice1,choice2,choice3}
```